# In which case Optimizer rearranges the conditons in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.6, execution-plan

recently I have added index "**new_index**" on this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `y` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shipping_provider_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_method_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tracking_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `is_used` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `shipping_provider_zone_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_response_reference` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tracking_number` (`tracking_number`,`shipping_provider_id`,`shipping_method_id`),
  KEY `fk_shipping_provider_tracking_number` (`shipping_provider_id`),
  KEY `fk_shipping_method_tracking_number` (`shipping_method_id`),
  KEY `is_used_shipping_provider_shipping_method_idx` (`is_used`,`shipping_provider_id`,`shipping_method_id`),
  KEY `fk_shipping_provider_zone_id` (`shipping_provider_zone_id`),
  KEY `new_index` (`shipping_provider_id`,`shipping_method_id`,`is_used`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_shipping_method_tracking_number` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_method_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_shipping_provider_tracking_number` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_provider_id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_shipping_provider_zone_id` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_provider_zone_id`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=383874548 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There are differences between EXPLAIN, Modified query from EXTENDED EXPLAIN.

```
mysql> explain extended select * from y
          where shipping_provider_id=325
            and shipping_method_id=2
            and is_used=0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: y
         type: ref
possible_keys: fk_shipping_provider_tracking_number,fk_shipping_method_tracking_number,is_used_shipping_provider_shipping_method_idx,new_index
          key: new_index
      key_len: 12
          ref: const,const,const
         rows: 3312914
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `x`.`y`.`id` AS `id`,`x`.`y`.`shipping_provider_id` AS `shipping_provider_id`,`x`.`y`.`shipping_method_id` AS `shipping_method_id`,`x`.`y`.`tracking_number` AS `tracking_number`,`x`.`y`.`is_used` AS `is_used`,`x`.`y`.`created` AS `created`,`x`.`y`.`updated` AS `updated`,`x`.`y`.`shipping_provider_zone_id` AS `shipping_provider_zone_id`,`x`.`y`.`api_response_reference` AS `api_response_reference`,`x`.`y`.`version` AS `version` from `x`.`y` 
     where ((`x`.`y`.`is_used` = 0)
        and (`x`.`y`.`shipping_method_id` = 2)
        and (`x`.`y`.`shipping_provider_id` = 325)) |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you see in the rewritten query, order of the conditions has reversed.
Can anyone tell in which conditions optimizer can choose low cardinal column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order of the conditions there is irrelevant. The optimizer has chosen to use `new_index` which seems to be the optimal index for this query. Why is the order of the conditions concerning you?

Comment: Is your question why MySQL reordered your predicates in show warnings? I'm not sure you can make assumptions on the order in which MySQL will evaluate your predicates based on that.

Comment: Without `new_index`, I would expect it to use `is_used_shipping_provider_shipping_method_idx` and run just as fast.

Comment: @RickJames In slave , same explain uses `is_used_shipping_provider_shipping_method_idx` for the query, run as fast  as you said. But chooses `new_index` in master.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean `AND` expressions are [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). In other words, the result of `A AND B` is the same as `B AND A`. So in an SQL query, any order of predicates in your WHERE clause is equivalent.

MySQL orders the predicates according to the order of columns in the index it chooses.

There is little or no advantage to ordering the columns by cardinality, either in the index definition or in the expression in your WHERE clause. If you have column `LC` and `HC` with low cardinality and high cardinality respectively, a search on `LC = 0 AND HC = 325` will be very nearly as efficient as a search on `HC = 325 AND LC = 0`.

If you disagree, then you should define your `is_used_shipping_provider_shipping_method_idx` index with the columns in the order you think they should be.